# Matching an element in a column, to others in the same column

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, list, numpy, dataframe

I have columns taken from excel as a dataframe, the columns are as follows:

```
HolidayTourProvider|Packages|Meals|Accommodation|LocalTravelVehicle|Cancellationfee
```

- Holiday Tour Provider has a couple of company names
- Packages, the features provided in each package are mostly the same like
- Meals,Accommodation etc... even though one company may call it "Saver", others may call it "Budget". (each of column mostly follow Yes/No, except Local travel vehicle are again car names like Ford Taurus,jeep cherokee etc..
- Cancellation amount is integers)

I need to write a function like

```
match(HolidayTP,Package)
```

where the user can give input like

```
match(AdventureLife, Luxury)
```

then I need to return all the packages that have similar features with `Luxury` by other Holiday Tour Providers, no matter what name they give the package like `'Semi Lux'`, `'Comfort'` etc...
I want to give a counter for every match and display all the packages that exceed the counter by 3 or 4.

This is my first python code. I am stuck here.
`fb` is the total df I exported to

```
def mapHol(HTP, PACKAGE):
    mfb = (fb['HTP']== HTP)&(fb['package']== package)
    B = fb[mfb]
    for i in fb[i]:
        for j in B[j]:
            if fb[i]==B[j]:
                count+=1
```

I dont know how to proceed, please help me this is my first major project, I started on my own.

Comment: hey buddy, thanks for showing us your function, however, it's totally meaningless unless we can reproduce your example - for that we need some sample input and expected output. Please provide these as text and not pictures./

Comment: As @Datanovice says, it's difficult to answer this kind of question. In general, you almost never need loops in `pandas`... Read about `df.loc` and filtering rows based on various conditions. You might also check out `df.groupby()`. Good luck!